# Is it possible to recover Deleted users?

Tags: plugins, database

I've accidentally deleted all of my WordPress site users and now I want to recover those deleted users? IS it possible? I've not created database backup so is it still possible?

Comment: There are some *maybe's*, but wow nasty issues never come alone. Taking a look [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/02/20/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-an-innodb-tablespace/) or maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6924888) at least could give some hope?! You don't give info about what situation you are in(server wise VPS/Shared hosting etc.).But for future moments.. I would make backups, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

When you work with any type of database it is of UTMOST importance to create regular backups. Once you delete something from a database it is gone forever. This is what they teach in the first class of any database course.

Here is a link to a [question in DB stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23251/is-there-a-way-to-recover-a-dropped-mysql-database)

I highly doubt they can do anything about it, but do contact your webhost to see if they can do anything.

Comment: Maybe they can do something about it if they have caching services, not too sure though.

Comment: Thank you guyz for taking time ! But I've decided to go other route.